# Generate const array of pointers to callback functions

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, c++17

I'd like to generate an array of N pointers to callbacks so I don't have to type them explicitly (LOC is not the issue here).
I use C++17.

Here is what I have:

```
using Callback = void(*)();
auto constexpr N = 2;

const Callback callbacks[N] = {
 [](){ auto i = 0; std::cout<<"callback " << i << "\n";},
 [](){ auto i = 1; std::cout<<"callback " << i << "\n";}
};

callbacks[0]();
callbacks[N-1]();
```

Here is what I want:

```
const auto callbacks = generate_callbacks<N>();  // or generate_callbacks(N)
callbacks[i](); // cout<<"callback " << i << "\n";
```

I tried various ways, but I keep running into the problems with constant parameters even when they are from a constexpr function or variadic template.

If I try this:

```
Callback callbacks[N] = { };

for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
{
callbacks[i] = [i](){ std::cout<<"callback " << i << "\n";};
}

for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
{
callbacks[i]();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:91:66: error: cannot convert ‘main()::’ to ‘Callback {aka void (*)()}’ in assignment
        callbacks[i] = [i](){ std::cout<<"callback " << i << "\n";};
```

If I make i static and leave out the capture it only uses the last value of i:

```
callback 2
callback 2
```

This is odd to me as capturing should be done at construction. Are the lambdas constructed after the loop exits?

As for the purpose. I want to apply this technique to generating interrupt handlers for microcontrollers. I can put the function pointers in the interrupt vector table directly. These functions have no parameters and I don't know a clean way to detect which interrupt source called the handler. I can write a handler for each interrupt, but I don't like repeating this code 6 times:

```
void handler0()
{
  do_something(0);
}
```

Typing it as a lambda and/or using a template makes it a little cleaner, but I still have to type something N times. And if N changes I have to change multiple lines of code. This is not elegant.

Comment: A capturing lambda does not decay to a function pointer.

Comment: @kryziek I know. I don't want to capture. I just want to generate a lambda with a compile time constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off Topic Suggestion: don't use, when you can, C-styles arrays but C++ `std::array`.

For example: the following line

```
const auto callbacks = generate_callbacks<N>();
```

can't works if you want that `callbacks` is a C-style array (a function can't return that type) but works when `generate_callback()` return a `std::array<Callback, N>` instance.

End of Off Topic Suggestion.

In this particular case, given that `N` is a `constexpr` value, I propose the use of template meta-programming.

So I suggest the following `generate_callbacks()` function, that just create a sequence of template values from zero to `N-1` and call an helper function

```
template <std::size_t N>
auto generate_callbacks ()
{ return gc_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

and a simple helper function that uses the template values and create the callbacks lambdas without capturing them (so remaining convertible to function pointers)

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::array<Callback, sizeof...(Is)> gc_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{ return {{ []{ auto i = Is; std::cout<<"callback " << i << "\n"; }... }}; }
```

If you can use C++20, using template lambdas you can avoid the external `gc_helper()` function and make all inside `generate_callbacks()` as follows

```
template <std::size_t N>
auto generate_callbacks ()
{
  return []<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> std::array<Callback, N>
  { return {{ []{ std::cout<<"callback " << Is << "\n"; }... }}; }
  (std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

The following is a full compiling <s>C++17</s> C++14 example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

using Callback = void(*)();
auto constexpr N = 2;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::array<Callback, sizeof...(Is)> gc_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{ return {{ []{ auto i = Is; std::cout<<"callback " << i << "\n"; }... }}; }

template <std::size_t N>
auto generate_callbacks ()
{ return gc_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }

int main()
{
  const auto callbacks = generate_callbacks<N>();

  for ( auto ui = 0 ; ui < N ; ++ui )
    callbacks[ui]();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile for me: https://onlinegdb.com/W2Ulz7WDX "error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:"

Comment: @elechris - I don't understand why... [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YMuVbSFrFe2DKzx1) compile it, C++17, without problems with both g++ and clang++. And the funny part is that onlinegdb compile if you change to C++20 (so it uses a fairly recent version of the compiler, if compile C++20).

Comment: I just checked. It also compiles and runs for C++14. Just not C++17. Very weird.

Comment: @elechris - Oh, yes: you're right: there is nothing specific C++17... needs C++14 just because `std::make_index_sequence<>` is introduced by C++14, but can be adapted also for C++11... yes, very weird that doesn't works with onlinegdb.

Comment: I figured it out. Online gdb uses gcc version: 7.5.0. With that version wandbox also gives the same error. But only c++17 uses that old version...

Comment: @elechris - Ah... different compilers for C++17 and C++20... yes, now make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The following compiles fine in both gcc and clang in C++17 mode. It uses some simple template metaprogramming to generate the sequence of callbacks.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using cb = void (*)();

template<int N>
inline auto fun()
{
    std::cout << "callback: " << N << '\n';
}

template<int N>
void init(cb * arr)
{
    arr[N] = &fun<N>;
    init<N-1>(arr);
}

template<>
void init<0>(cb * arr)
{
    arr[0] = &fun<0>;
}

template<int N>
struct callbacks
{
    callbacks()
    {
        init<N>(cbs.data());
    }
    
    std::array<cb, N> cbs;
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = callbacks<4>();
    for (auto x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
    {
        foo.cbs[x]();
    }
}
```